# Why does installing an npm package re-install all my other packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I have this annoying issue where when I try to install a new package with npm it starts installing all my other packages, often breaking something and forcing me to reinstall my node modules. What could be the problem and how could I fix this?

[image]

Comment: What commands are you running... why would a clean install break your project? That suggests you have bigger issues

Comment: make sure you have a package-lock.json and if you don't want stuff to change, then "pin" your dependencies by specifying their exact version in package.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not install all your other packages, what it does is it just installs all the dependencies in order to actually install the `gatsby-source-contentful`.

You can see the dependencies of the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-source-contentful) in the dependencies tab.
Of course, those dependencies might have more dependencies so it's just a chain of installations and updates.

For example the `gatsby-source-contentful` package, there is a dependency called `gatsby-source-filesystem` which has a dependency on the `file-type` so that's why it tries to update that.